# drupal paypal order email sending twice

Tags: drupal, paypal, ubercart

I am using ubercart paypal module as payment gateway in drupal.. when the user pays the money the order confirmation is sent twice. this should not happen..

please help me..

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by the Paypal IPN sending out multiple requests which in turn causes the Conditional Actions module to invoke the email action twice.

Comment #25 in [this post](http://www.ubercart.org/forum/support/10422/multiple_emails_single_purchase) presents a possible solution. You should also check these links out:

1. http://www.ubercart.org/forum/support/10422/multiple_emails_single_purchase
2. http://www.ubercart.org/forum/support/8790/stock_level_reduced_twice
3. http://www.ubercart.org/forum/support/8930/stock_reduced_twice
4. http://www.ubercart.org/forum/support/14097/duplicate_notifications_file_download_sales_upgrading_uc_20
5. http://www.ubercart.org/forum/bug_reports/13313/paypal_duplicate_actions_taken
6. http://www.ubercart.org/forum/bug_reports/13716/stock_levels_decrease_twice_latest_update_6x20
7. http://www.ubercart.org/forum/support/13794/file_download_user_notified_twice
8. http://www.ubercart.org/forum/support/5192/stock_decreased_2_times_once_customer_buys_once_customer_pays_paypal

They all talk about the same problem in one way or another.